# Responsive Design Fail

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, header, media-queries

I am having an issue with trying to figure out why the header on my mobile format isn't showing up.... can anyone see something I can't?? I have been trying for two weeks and I must be missing something. It appears that my larger version is working just fine, but I would appreciate any help I can get with this problem.  Thank you.

```css
/* very small mobile styles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
 html,
 body {
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #682876;
 }
 .container-header {
  display: none;
 }
 .container-header-mobile {
  height: 260px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #682876;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0;
 }
 .container-header-mobile img {
  max-height: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: auto;
 }
 .container-header-mobile a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
 }
 main {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }
 main img {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
 }
 figure {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
 }
 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: rgba(104, 40, 118, 0.5);
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -30%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
 }
 figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
 }
 .cap-bot figcaption {
  left: 0;
  bottom: -30%;
 }
 .cap-bot:hover figcaption {
  bottom: 0;
 }
 h1 {
  font-family: "Caveat", cursive;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 0.75em;
 }
 p {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.5em;
 }
 main a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 .bot-social {
  margin: auto;
 }
 .bot-social img {
  border-radius: 18px;
 }
 footer {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
 }
 footer a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
}

/* mobile portrait styles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 html,
 body {
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #682876;
 }
 .container-header {
  display: none;
 }
 .container-header-mobile {
  height: 260px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  color: #682876;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0;
 }
 .container-header-mobile img {
  max-height: 100px;
  min-height: 50px;
  width: auto;
 }
 .container-header-mobile a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
 }
 main {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 2%;
  margin: 0;
 }
 main img {
  max-width: 370px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
 }
 figure {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
 }
 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: rgba(104, 40, 118, 0.5);
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -30%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
 }
 figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
 }
 .cap-bot figcaption {
  left: 0;
  bottom: -30%;
 }
 .cap-bot:hover figcaption {
  bottom: 0;
 }
 h1 {
  font-family: "Caveat", cursive;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 1em;
 }
 p {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.5em;
 }
 main a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 .bot-social {
  margin: auto;
 }
 .bot-social img {
  border-radius: 18px;
 }
 footer {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
 }
 footer a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
}
/* laptop styles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
 html,
 body {
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #682876;
 }
 .container-header-mobile {
  display: none;
 }
 .container-header {
  height: 260px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #682876;
  background-color: white;
 }
 .container-header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
 }
 .container-header img {
  max-height: 230px;
  width: auto;
  padding-right: 12%;
 }
 .bot-social {
  display: none;
 }
 .top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
 }
 .top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
 }
 .top-left img {
  padding: 5px;
 }
 main {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 2%;
  margin: 0;
 }
 main img {
  max-width: 370px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
 }
 figure {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
 }
 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: rgba(104, 40, 118, 0.5);
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -30%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
 }
 figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
 }
 .cap-bot figcaption {
  left: 0;
  bottom: -30%;
 }
 .cap-bot:hover figcaption {
  bottom: 0;
 }
 h1 {
  font-family: "Caveat", cursive;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 2em;
 }
 p {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
 }
 main a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 .bot-social {
  margin: auto;
 }
 footer {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
 }
 footer a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
}
/* large laptop styles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1362px) {
 html,
 body {
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #682876;
 }
 .container-header-mobile {
  display: none;
 }
 .container-header {
  height: 260px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #682876;
  background-color: white;
 }
 .container-header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
 }
 .container-header img {
  max-height: 230px;
  width: auto;
  padding-right: 12%;
 }
 .bot-social {
  display: none;
 }
 .top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
 }
 .top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
 }
 .top-left img {
  padding: 5px;
 }
 main {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 2%;
  margin: 0;
 }
 main img {
  width: 236px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
 }
 figure {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
 }
 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: rgba(104, 40, 118, 0.5);
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -30%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
 }
 figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
 }
 .cap-bot figcaption {
  left: 0;
  bottom: -30%;
 }
 .cap-bot:hover figcaption {
  bottom: 0;
 }
 h1 {
  font-family: "Caveat", cursive;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 2em;
 }
 p {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
 }
 main a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 .bot-social {
  margin: auto;
 }
 footer {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
 }
 footer a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
}
/* desktop styles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1440px) {
 html,
 body {
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #682876;
 }
 .container-header-mobile {
  display: none;
 }
 .container-header {
  height: 260px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #682876;
  background-color: white;
 }
 .container-header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
 }
 .container-header img {
  max-height: 230px;
  width: auto;
  padding-right: 12%;
 }
 .bot-social {
  display: none;
 }
 .top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
 }
 .top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
 }
 .top-left img {
  padding: 5px;
 }
 main {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 2%;
  margin: 0;
 }
 main img {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
 }
 figure {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
 }
 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: rgba(104, 40, 118, 0.5);
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -30%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
 }
 figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
 }
 .cap-bot figcaption {
  left: 0;
  bottom: -30%;
 }
 .cap-bot:hover figcaption {
  bottom: 0;
 }
 h1 {
  font-family: "Caveat", cursive;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 2em;
 }
 p {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
 }
 main a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 .bot-social {
  margin: auto;
 }
 footer {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
 }
 footer a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
}
/* HD styles */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px) {
 html,
 body {
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #682876;
 }
 .container-header-mobile {
  display: none;
 }
 .container-header {
  height: 260px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #682876;
  background-color: white;
 }
 .container-header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 5px;
 }
 .container-header img {
  max-height: 230px;
  width: auto;
  padding-right: 12%;
 }
 .bot-social {
  display: none;
 }
 .top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
 }
 .top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
 }
 .top-left img {
  padding: 5px;
 }
 main {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 2%;
  margin: 0;
 }
 main img {
  max-width: 300%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
 }
 figure {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
 }
 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: rgba(104, 40, 118, 0.5);
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -30%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
 }
 figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
 }
 .cap-bot figcaption {
  left: 0;
  bottom: -30%;
 }
 .cap-bot:hover figcaption {
  bottom: 0;
 }
 h1 {
  font-family: "Caveat", cursive;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 2em;
 }
 p {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
 }
 main a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 .bot-social {
  margin: auto;
 }
 footer {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
 }
 footer a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Volume Salon Westlake</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat|Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="container-header">
      <div class="top-left">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/volumesalonwestlake/" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1671394/FB-f-Logo__blue_29.png" alt="Facebook">
 </a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/1732209880415699/volume-salon/" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1671394/glyph-logo_May2016.png" alt="Instagram">
 </a>
      </div>
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1671394/header.jpg" alt="VS Logo">
      <div class="top-right">
        <p><b>26101 Center Ridge Rd. Westlake, OH 44145</b></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-header-mobile">
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1671394/header.jpg" alt="VS Logo"><br>
      <p><b>26101 Center Ridge Rd. Westlake, OH 44145</b></p>
    </div>

  </header>

  <main>
    <div>
      <h1>Volume Salon, located in Westlake, Ohio is... To view offered services and schedule an appointment with one of our independent sylists, visit the links below:</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
      <figure class="cap-bot">
        <a href="Nikki.html"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1671394/nikki.png" alt="Nikki"></a>
        <figcaption>Nikki</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="cap-bot">
        <a href="Kevin.html"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1671394/kevin.png" alt="Kevin"></a>
        <figcaption>Kevin</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="cap-bot">
        <a href="Kelley.html"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1671394/kelley2.png" alt="Kelley"></a>
        <figcaption>Kelley</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="cap-bot">
        <a href="Anne-Marie.html"><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1671394/anne-marie.jpg" alt="Anne-Marie"></a>
        <figcaption>Anne-Marie</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="bot-social">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/volumesalonwestlake/" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1671394/FB-f-Logo__blue_29.png" alt="Facebook">
 </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/1732209880415699/volume-salon/" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1671394/glyph-logo_May2016.png" alt="Instagram">
 </a>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2018 Volume Salon</p>
    <p>Made with &hearts; by <a href="https://codepen.io/valsburger/" target="_blank">Valarie Pisarcik</a></p>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your header doesn't show up in width fewer than `320px` because you set `dispaly: none`.

```
.container-header {
    display: none;
}
```

please change it to :

```
.container-header {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/NBaNXv

Remember that CSS code cascades. If your stylesheet has

```
.element{
     display:block;
}  

.....

.element{
     display:none;
}
```

then the display property for .element will be none.

In your CSS code you have

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {

    .container-header-mobile {
        height: 260px;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        color: #682876;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 0;
    }

}

...

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

    .container-header-mobile {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

There are two ways to stop one media query from overriding another.

In my pen I modified your media queries by adding a (min-width) to each of them, eg

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {  
  ...
}  
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 768px) {  
  ...
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
   ...
}
```

the other option is to reverse the order of your media queries, have the desktop viewport first and the mobile viewport last:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1441px) {
...
}  
@media only screen and (max-width: 1440px) {
...
}  
@media only screen and (max-width: 1362px) {  
...
}
```

Hope this helps!